# Local matplotlib display in PyCharm with remote ssh interpreter from Google Cloud Platform's Compute Engine

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I am currently running Python 3.5 scripts on two VM instances on GCP from a local PyCharm session running on my Mac (see below for detailed environment specifications).

I have two different projects in GCP which look similar. I reviewed their setup with our cloud admin and we can't see any major difference, at least any trivial one. I created two Deep Learning images on GCP using the following cloud SDK command line, one within each project:

```
export PROJECT=[MY_PROJECT_NAME]

export INSTANCE_ROOT=$USER-vm
export ZONE=europe-west4-a
export IMAGE_FAMILY=tf-latest-gpu
export INSTANCE_TYPE=n1-highmem-8

export GPU_TYPE=v100
export GPU_COUNT=1
export INSTANCE_NAME=$INSTANCE_ROOT-$GPU_TYPE-$GPU_COUNT
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-$GPU_TYPE,count=$GPU_COUNT \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata=install-nvidia-driver=True \
        --scopes=storage-rw
```

Both images are completely similar.

I configured two remote ssh interpreters in PyCharm and deployed my Python code on both virtual machines. Everything is absolutely similar in terms of VM instance configuration (OS, Python version / libs, source code, etc.) and PyCharm remote interpreter configuration.
In both cases, the ssh ingress connection to the instance (on port 22) works pretty well.

Yet, when calling `plt.show()` to display images using matplotlib, the images get displayed in one setup but not in the other one.

This is not a matter of setting the proper ssh configuration (`-X` option on the command line, `X11Forwarding`, etc.). I already checked that, and anyway one of my VMs does a pretty good job of displaying my images within this configuration.

I debugged the execution and discovered that PyCharm automatically handles X display by implementing its own matplotlib `FigureCanvas`. When in remote ssh, the `show()` function actually opens a socket on the defined host (i.e. my local Mac) and sends the buffer to be displayed:

```
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    [..]
    sock.send(buffer)
```

This is precisely where my two configurations diverge:

1. The one working tries to connect on `localhost:53725` and succeeds:
   `<socket.socket fd=28, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 42316), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 53725)>`
2. The one failing tries to connect on `localhost:53725` as well but gets an exception.

My strongest assumption is that some network configuration in the two GCP projects differs somehow and prevents the connection on `localhost:53725` for the second one.
However, beyond that I have no idea what might happen and/or how to fix it.

Any idea / suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Laurent

--

Detailed environment specifications:
PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018
Licensed to PyCharm Evaluator
Expiration date: October 27, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It seems to be a bug and I found a workaround.
I share it as it might save hours of troubleshooting and debugging to anyone stumbling on the same problem.

The problem actually occurs when you remain in the same PyCharm session and switch from one interpreter to the other one.
If you quit PyCharm and start it again, the local display will work with either of the interpreters / VMs you run first. Then, if you switch to the second one it fails.
Everything looks as if there were some kind of lock set on the port or anywhere else by PyCharm which prevents you from switching seamlessly from one interpreter to another.

I'll share these insights with the PyCharm support team. BTW, other than that, this local display feature with remote interpreters is awesome and works just fine.